# Split a document by string and output as .pdf - Split function not working

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a large word doc (100 pages) and I am trying to split the document into several smaller docs and then save each one as a .pdf into a user defined location. I so far have it splitting by the delimiter and saving as a .pdf no problem at all.
The split function on the other hand seems to be removing all formatting from the page and just outputting as plain text. Is there any way around this as formatting is necessary? Coincidentally, the split is meant to be every 3 pages... Is there a way to set the range to a block of 3 pages maybe?

```
Sub SplitNotes(delim As String, strFileName As String)
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    Dim X
    Dim Doc As Document

    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fDialog
        .Title = "Select folder to save split files"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            MsgBox "Cancelled By User"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    DocDir = fDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1)

        arrNotes = Split(ActiveDocument.Range, delim)

        Response = MsgBox("This will split the document into " & UBound(arrNotes) + 1 & " sections. Do you wish to preceed?", 4)
        If Response = 7 Then Exit Sub
        For I = LBound(arrNotes) To UBound(arrNotes)
            If Trim(arrNotes(I)) <> "" Then
            X = X + 1
            ActiveDocument.Range = arrNotes(I)
            ActiveDocument.Range.Copy
            Set Doc = Documents.Add
            ActiveDocument.Range.Paste
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=DocDir & "\" & X & ".PDF", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
            ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
            End If
        Next     
    End With
End Sub

Sub test()
    'delimiter & filename
SplitNotes "MyText", "Notes "
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will select three pages and copy them to a new one, which will be saved as PDF, then the next three pages will be selected and copied and so on.

There is still some problem with an empty additional page, which I could not solve now.

```
Sub SplitDocument()

Dim rgePages As Range

iCurrentPage = 1
Set docMultiple = ActiveDocument
iPageCount = docMultiple.Content.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)

counter = 0
Do Until (counter * 3) + 1 > iPageCount

    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=(counter * 3) + 1
    Set rgePages = Selection.Range
    counter = counter + 1
    If counter * 3 > iPageCount Then
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=iPageCount
    Else
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=(counter * 3)
    End If
    rgePages.End = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End
    rgePages.Select

    rgePages.Copy
    Set docSingle = Documents.Add
    docSingle.Range.Paste

    strNewFileName = "C:\Temp\DocumentPart" & "_" & counter & ".PDF"
    docSingle.SaveAs strNewFileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF

    docSingle.Close SaveChanges:=False
    rgePages.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
Loop

End Sub
```